# Maximizing/Minimizing triangle area

Tags: calculus

[image: The problem]

[image: What I got so far]

I think I set it up right and I know area of a triangle is 1/2(BH). So I get 1/2(xy) and then try to maximize/minimize X? What do I plug in for Y?

Comment: Please use parentheses when using the slash for division.  Sometimes when we see $1/2(BH)$ it means $\frac 1{2BH}$, sometimes (as here) it means $\frac {BH}2$.  Either $BH/2$ or $(1/2)BH$ or \frac {BH}2 between dollar signs to get the stacked fraction (preferred).  Some hints are [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Since the point is on the curve $y=\exp(\frac {-x}3)$ that is what you should use for $y$.  Then you can maximize over $x$.

Added:  The area of the triangle is $A=\frac 12x\exp(\frac {-x}3)$  Then $\frac{dA}{dx}=\frac 12\left( \exp(\frac{-x}3)-\frac x3\exp(\frac{-x}3)\right)$ Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates of the vertices of the right triangle are (0,0) , (x,0), (x,y) but they tell you that the third point is on the curve y=Exp[-x/3]. So, the coordinates of the vertices are (0,0) , (x,0), (x,Exp[-x/3]). So the area is given by S = x Exp[-x/3] / 2. Since you want to find extremum values of theis area, its derivative (with respect to x, the only unknown) must be zero. Are you able to continue with this ?

Comment: Okay so I found the derivative and set it = to 0 and got x=6, which is out of the domain?

Comment: Yeah nevermind I made some algebra mistakes, but I'm still left with the wrong answer. My derivative is ((e^-x/3)/2)-((xe^-x/3)/6)

Comment: Factor Exp[-x/3] in order to simplify your derivative (which is correct). You should not get x=6 as a solution but x=?

Comment: @RossMillikan. Thanks for reporting the typo

Comment: @user104827. Do not forget that you also must find the smallest area.

Comment: I get x=3, which isn't right. Any ideas?

Comment: x=3 is the solution for the maximum area. What about the minimum area ?

Comment: Sorry I am taking so long to respond. Thats the only value I get when I set the derivative = to 0?

Comment: The minimum value in the interval does not necessarily correpond to a point where the derivative vanishes. Since you found the maximum, does it mean that after the function decreases ? Can you continue with this ?